# JavaScript OOP 'this' scope not working

Tags: javascript, oop

Map class:

```
function Map() {
    this.map;
    this.userLatitude = 0;
    this.userLongitude = 0;

    this.startPositionReporting();
}

Map.prototype.getUserPosition = function () {
    alert(this.userLatitude);

    return { 
        latitude: this.userLatitude,
        longitude: this.userLongitude
    };
};

Map.prototype.startPositionReporting = function () {
    var geolocationOptions = {
        enableHighAccuracy : true
    };

    function showError(error) {
        switch(error.code) {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                alert("Location information is unavailable.");
                break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                alert("The request to get user location timed out.");
                break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                alert("An unknown error occurred.");
                break;
        }
    }

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            this.userLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
            this.userLongitude = position.coords.longitude;
        }, null, geolocationOptions);
    }
};
```

Calling the object:

```
var mapObject = new Map();
console.log(mapObject.getUserPosition()); // Why does this return 0???
```

I can't figure out why `mapObject.getUserPosition()` is returning 0. I have checked `this.userLatitude` and `this.userLongitude` inside the `startPositionReporting` method and they work fine. This must be something to do with scope... any ideas?

Comment: Quick thought... it looks like a scope issue. Put `var _this = this;` before your navigator code and change `this` to `_this` in the return function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several. The problem is that `this` doesn't behave the way you think it does.

`this` is bound to a function's scope, and is resolved dynamically (at the time the function is called).

Your problem is that you've got a callback fed to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`, where, in that function, you're setting properties on `this`, expecting `this` to be your instance.

It's not.

`this` is most-likely `window`, in your case.

Two solutions are:

```
Map.prototype.startPositionReporting = function () {
    var map = this; // instance of Map

    /* ...  */
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        map.userLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
        // ...
    });
```

or

```
var updateMapCoords = function (position) {
        this.userLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
        // ...
};


Map.prototype.startPositionReporting = function () {
    var map = this; // instance of Map
    var updateMap = updateMapCoords.bind(map);
    // returns a copy of the function with `this` set to the value passed to `bind`
    // ...

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(updateMap);
    // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is the scope problem.

```
  var that = this;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            that.userLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
            that.userLongitude = position.coords.longitude;
        }, null, geolocationOptions);
    }
```

The function that you pass in getCurrentPosition will be invoked in a different context. That is why you need to save off the reference to the context where that function was invoked.

Comment: Cheers dude! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is an asynchronous function. You need to wait until  it returns before those fields will be anything other than 0.

Comment: I did wait, I made sure that I called the function after the position was assigned.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle that demonstrates your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simple

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        this.userLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
        this.userLongitude = position.coords.longitude;
    }, null, geolocationOptions);
}
```

In this part of the `startPositionReporting` -method you assume that inside your anonymous function the `this` variable still references your Map object. Well, it doesn't. You need to explicitly store the scope you want to use in a variable and then use it within the anonymous function closure, like this:

```
var self = this;

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        self.userLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
        self.userLongitude = position.coords.longitude;
    }, null, geolocationOptions);
}
```

Hope this helps!